# Linux one line command to gzip and move

Tags: unix, gzip, move

I have some .txt file in a particular /path/doc.txt  and i wish to gzip all the files and move the new file that zipped all txt file into another path. How will i achieve that in one line of code.

Comment: You can't use gzip by itself to package multiple files into a single compressed file. You would need to use tar with gzip, or use zip.

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like:

```
find /path/doc/ -type f -name \*.txt | xargs tar -z -c -f save.tar.gz && mv save.tar.gz other/path
```

use

```
tar  -vtf save.tar.gz
```

to check archive content